# Is there a way to install an older version of IntelliJ with Brew?

Tags: intellij-idea, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I'm looking to install a specific version of IntelliJ using Brew, as one of the add-ons I'm using is not supported in the latest version.

Is there a way in Brew to do that?

Comment: Is using brew mandatory? You can download and install previous IDEA releases from here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html, also there is a Toolbox app: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I would like to use a terminal command for that rather than a UI. In the first link, a developer has to look manually for the right version and I'm looking to save them doing that

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam was hoping for something simpler honestly

Comment: What you mean simpler than installing specific version of a formula? Don't you want to install a "specific version of IntelliJ using Brew"?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I meant without scripting my own formula, was hoping for something ready made that wouldn't require maintenance

Comment: @DinaNeishtadt you don't have to create your own formula. There is an existing formula just do `brew install intellij-idea@<version>` example `brew install intellij-idea@2020.1`

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam on Mac if I do `brew install intellij-idea@2020.1` or `brew install intellij-idea@2020.1.4`, I get error ` No similarly named formulae found` and `No formulae found in taps`

Answer (score 3):

I just made a tap for this [hamidnazari/homebrew-jetbrains-versions](https://github.com/hamidnazari/homebrew-jetbrains-versions).

```
brew tap hamidnazari/jetbrains-versions
brew install intellij-idea@2020.1.4
```

Give it a go and let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Should it work with `brew install intellij-idea@2023.1.3`? Not working for me

Comment: @henryabra I didn't have the latest minor releases in the tap. It's updated now. Update and pull `intellij-idea@2023.1.4` instead as the tap only has the latest minors not the ones in between.